# "attribute <items> is of the wrong type: " in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-apps

i am trying to use a wrapper class list in aura:attribute i am getting the error **org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: attribute  is of the wrong type:**

i'm not sure why this is happening

> Component

```
<aura:component controller="DispositionController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">   

<aura:attribute name="inventoryList" type="lotWrapper[]" default="[]" description="This attr. will hold all product Info"/>


</aura:component >
```

> Apex class

```
public class lotWrapper {

@AuraEnabled public list<string> reasonToChange{get;set;}

@AuraEnabled public string newStatusVal{get;set;}

@AuraEnabled public string allocateAttrVal{get;set;}


@AuraEnabled public List<productListwrap> productListwrap{get;set;}

public lotWrapper(){

}
    public class productListwrap
    {

    @AuraEnabled public Inventory_Detail__c invDetail{get;set;}

    }
}
```

any help appreciated this is really urgent to me

[image: getting this error]

Comment: Do you have an attribute called `items` somewhere - the message looks like it does not relate to `inventoryList`.

Comment: Yes, and also can you show us the iteratator that is iterating on the `items` array

Comment: Post the apex code which returns the list of wrapper to the component side.

Comment: Try removing default="[]" for your inventoryList attribute. It solved problem for me. You could use 'init' event and set value from js handler (helper or controller) if you really need default for that.